# Keeping zeros in data with sklearn

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

I have a csv dataset that I'm trying to use with sklearn. The goal is to predict future webtraffic. However, my dataset contains zeros on days that there were no visitors and I'd like to keep that value. There are more days with zero visitors then there are with visitors (it's a tiny tiny site). Here's a look at the data

Col1 is the date:
 10/1/11
 10/2/11
 10/3/11
 etc....

Col2 is the # of visitors: 
12
1
0
0
1
5
0
0
etc....

sklearn seems to interpret the zero values as NaN values which is understandable. How can I use those zero values in a logistic function (is that even possible)?

Update:
The estimator is https://github.com/facebookincubator/prophet and when I run the following:

```
df = pd.read_csv('~/tmp/datafile.csv')
df['y'] = np.log(df['y'])
df.head()

m = Prophet()
m.fit(df);

future = m.make_future_dataframe(periods=365)
future.tail()

forecast = m.predict(future)
forecast[['ds', 'yhat', 'yhat_lower', 'yhat_upper']].tail()

m.plot(forecast);

m.plot_components(forecast);
plt.show
```

I get the following:

```
growthprediction.py:7: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log
  df['y'] = np.log(df['y'])
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/fbprophet/forecaster.py:307: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
  k = (df['y_scaled'].ix[i1] - df['y_scaled'].ix[i0]) / T
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "growthprediction.py", line 11, in <module>
    m.fit(df);
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/fbprophet/forecaster.py", line 387, in fit
    params = model.optimizing(dat, init=stan_init, iter=1e4)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pystan/model.py", line 508, in optimizing
    ret, sample = fit._call_sampler(stan_args)
  File "stanfit4anon_model_35bf14a7f93814266f16b4cf48b40a5a_4758371668158283666.pyx", line 804, in stanfit4anon_model_35bf14a7f93814266f16b4cf48b40a5a_4758371668158283666.StanFit4Model._call_sampler (/var/folders/ym/m6j7kw0d3kj_0frscrtp58800000gn/T/tmp5wq7qltr/stanfit4anon_model_35bf14a7f93814266f16b4cf48b40a5a_4758371668158283666.cpp:16585)
  File "stanfit4anon_model_35bf14a7f93814266f16b4cf48b40a5a_4758371668158283666.pyx", line 398, in stanfit4anon_model_35bf14a7f93814266f16b4cf48b40a5a_4758371668158283666._call_sampler (/var/folders/ym/m6j7kw0d3kj_0frscrtp58800000gn/T/tmp5wq7qltr/stanfit4anon_model_35bf14a7f93814266f16b4cf48b40a5a_4758371668158283666.cpp:8818)
RuntimeError: k initialized to invalid value (nan)
```

Comment: It depends on the estimator which you are trying. Please explain your question more, with the estimator you want to try.

Comment: Added in a update that explains things a bit more.

Answer (score 1):

In this line of your code:

```
df['y'] = np.log(df['y'])
```

you are taking logarithm of 0 when your df['y'] is zero, which results in warnings and NaNs in your resulting dataset, because logarithm of 0 is not defined.

sklearn itself does NOT interpret zero values as NaNs unless you replace them with NaNs in your preprocessing.